# How to map and summarize a sequence of inputs with custom function in R?

Tags: r, filter, purrr

Here is a sample dataframe, which is a machine learning prediction:

```
df <- tibble(
  actual = rnorm(100,0,1),
  pred = rnorm(100,0,1))
```

I'd like to measure the accuracy in predicting the sign of the actual value, after filtering for various ranges of `pred`(i.e. `pred>10`,`pred>20`,`pred>30`,`pred>40` etc).

Below is a function I wrote:

```
predacc <- function(x,n){
  x%>%
    filter(pred > n)%>%
    summarize(acc = mean(sign(actual) == sign(pred)))
}
```

The operation below correctly shows the accuracy in predicting the sign when predicted value > 50:

```
predacc(df_evalrf,50)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
    acc
  <dbl>
1 0.854
```

I would like to do the same for values `1:100`, tried the below method but it did not work:

```
map(df,~predacc(.x,seq(1:100,by=1)))
 Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
result <- purrr::map_df(1:100, predacc, x = df)
```

Or in base R :

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:100, predacc, x = df))
```

Are you sure, you want to use `1:100` though since the numbers which you have generated using `rnorm` are with `mean = 0` and `sd = 1`. Did you mean to use `seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)` ?

Comment: Thanks! It works great. Yeah I meant to use seq(0, 1, by = 0.01). Thanks!